# Programmatically import a CSV file into an Access database using C#

Tags: c#, csv, ms-access, insert

I have a CSV file with no header as the first row and I am trying to insert the data into an Access database that I have created. I want to be able to insert all of the data without having to specify each column name because I am going to be writing a statement similar for 20+ tables. I also wish to know how to insert a CSV file into an Access database if both files are in different locations.

Below is my code, I am using C#. I am receiving an error:

> The INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field name: 'F1'. Make sure you have typed the name correctly, and try the operation again.

If there is a better way to perform this task than the way I am currently doing it then feel free to share your opinion.

```
private void btnBulk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbCommand cmdBulk = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO tbl_Summary " + 
            @"SELECT * FROM [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=NO;ACCDB=YES;Database=C:\Database].[SalesData.csv]", MyConn);

    MyConn.Open();
    cmdBulk.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MyConn.Close();
}
```

Comment: tbl_Summary contains 25 columns, none of which are named F1.

Comment: Did you find a way to do it ? I am facing the same problem !

Answer (score -1):

Why won't you import the csv using Access with Get External Data wizard.

[Import data into an Access database](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-data-into-an-Access-database-782703aa-6b21-4458-9429-480eaf0c71d6)

Comment: Because the program I am creating has to do it automatically through c#